# How do I change the url for get_site_url() in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have a website which has a sister site linked to it (mysite.com/sistersite). When you click on the sister site's logo it redirects you back to the original site (mysite.com). I would like to for it to direct only to the sister site's homepage when clicked.

This is the bit of code in the sister site's header.php where I believe I need to change the get_site_url().

What are my options for changing this function?

```
<?php
       $homeimgdet='/" class="mm-logo"><img border="0" id="tlogo" 

       src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/';

       $homelogo='<a href="'.get_site_url();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to append the sister site subdirectory to the variable string:

```
<?php
$homeimgdet='/" class="mm-logo"><img border="0" id="tlogo" 

src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/';

$homelogo='<a href="'.get_site_url().'/sistersite';
```

However, if this sister site is a subsite of a multisite installation, it may be easier to use `get_home_url()`:

```
<?php
$homeimgdet='/" class="mm-logo"><img border="0" id="tlogo" 

src="'.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/img/';

$homelogo='<a href="'.get_home_url();
```